# how to extract string between 2 strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

need help with extracting a string from CLOB field (the field called 'note')

I want to extract everything between "Reasons added" to "Reasons removed" in the string I show below. 
for making it a bit more complicated, sometimes the reason removed isn't appearing so I need to get everything from reason added to the end. 
In addition, I don't want to take strings in parenthesis "()" .
So far, I have managed to extract only part from the desired string.

CLOB value :

```
"Change step forward
Note added
Step changed from [OFF] to [ON]
Reasons added: test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , sometest4& and5(Type)
Reasons removed: test6- test7(Type)"


TO_CHAR(TRIM(
    regexp_substr(
    (case when note like '%Reasons removed:%' then regexp_substr(note, 'Reasons added:\s(.*?)\sReasons removed:.*', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
    else (case when note like '%Reasons added:%' then REGEXP_SUBSTR(note,'[^:]+$') end) end),'[^(]+'))) "CODE"

test1 , some test 2, test3 , sometest4& and5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I added another value into the table, that doesn't contain the "Reasons removed" string.

Basically, it selects everything between "Reasons added" and "Reasons removed" if it exists; if not, takes everything from "Reasons added" to the end. `CASE` takes care about that.

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"Change step forward
Note added
Step changed from [OFF] to [ON]
Reasons added: test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , sometest4& and5(Type)
Reasons removed: test6- test7(Type)"

"This is text without "Reas. remov."
Note added
Step changed from [OFF] to [ON]
Reasons added: test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , and this would be the end"


SQL> select trim(substr(col,
  2                instr(col, 'Reasons added') + 14,
  3                --
  4                case when instr(col, 'Reasons removed') > 0 then
  5                  instr(col, 'Reasons removed') - instr(col, 'Reasons added') - 14
  6                else
  7                  length(col)
  8                end)) result
  9  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , sometest4& and5(Type)
test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , and this would be the end"

SQL>
```

Comment: great, it works! thank you .
do you happen to know how to remove the (type) from the string ?

Comment: You're welcome. Remove it with the REPLACE function, e.g. `replace(col, '(Type)', '')`

Comment: oh that's right.. silly question. thanks again ! :)

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) function as below

```
with tab(str) as
(
 select 'Change step forward
         Note added
         Step changed from [OFF] to [ON]
         Reasons added: test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , sometest4& and5(Type)
         Reasons removed: test6- test7(Type)' from dual        
)
select regexp_substr(str,'Reasons added:\s(.*?)\s.*\sReasons removed',1,1,null,1)
    as "Result String"
  from tab;

Result String
---------------------------------------------------------------
test1 (Type), some test 2 (Type), test3 , sometest4& and5(Type)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22b3e68ce52a70dde28dcb2ec79c22b4)</kbd>